# TFS 2013 Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Team Explorer

Tags: tfs

I have a couple of TP in a single TPC in a TFS 2013 server. Everything was working normal until yesterday I started to get errors when getting the latest version. The error is:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when getting file $collection/folder/file.dll

Its like a reference to the file was saved but not the actual file...

When I checked the TFS web access the file appears there but I couldn't download it, yet I am able to download other files.

I have tried to delete such file with tf delete but I keep getting "File not found"

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I tried running some tf commands on the server and I got to the root of the problem. The server was out of disk space.